# wildcard not working to change directory

Tags: php, windows

i cant use * or ? for change directory

```
chdir ("c:\win*\system*");
```

how it work, i cant guess full name of windows whats that, for example WIN or winxp or win7.
or how to guess whats full name of that

Comment: What if there is two folders, `C:\win1` and `C:\win2`?

Comment: You can't do it because it's not tractible, for the reason chelmertz indicates. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: i dont think any body have 2 directory like win1 or win2

Comment: Eveything is possible should be the first thing a real / good developer should say. Instead of simply nobody has that. It's waiting for bad things to happen.

Comment: i can use * in linux operating system but i can't use that in windows

Comment: Which part in http://php.net/chdir makes you believe you could use wildcards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely misunderstanding that [`chdir`](http://php.net/chdir) is equal to windows [`chdir` (`cd`)](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/chdir.mspx) in the windows operating system. But it is not.

However that should not pose you any problems because PHP and the shell can work together easily:

```
chdir(rtrim(`cd c:\win*\system* & cd`));
echo getcwd();
```

Example output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system
```

If you know what command is for what, you can easily solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`chdir()` to a random wildcard directory supposed to be chosen by the system for you in case of collissions? *Really?!*

**Paths are explicit.** *It's here or there... not somewhere, just look it up for me.* And why try to access system directory from PHP in the first place? Got permissions setup right? Or you want to make modifications to users that use your script and can't guess the right path yourself?

> Imagine that this guy's `chdir()` has to list paths in multiple
>   folders everytime to do one simple operation. Let's talk **security**,
>   **performance**... but most of all... **common sense**.

*The things I see on SO...*

**PS**: *I -1'ed you.* This question should not be asked by a developer with minimal understanding of... development stuff. Want to inject stuff into system dir, don't use PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this:

> **CHDIR allows wildcards as path names, and changes to the first directory found whose name matches the wildcard specified**. This is convenient with long directory names, as it is only necessary to type enough of the path to uniquely identify the directory, and then add a trailing "*" to the path name.
>   http://www.rcramer.com/tech/windows/cmd/ad.html#CHDIR

[image: chdir]

It is not PHP though...

Comment: `C:\Users\alachiq>cd c:\win*\
The directory name is invalid.

C:\Users\alachiq>`

Comment: It actually might be the case. Try `dir c: /a:d /b` to see the list of folders.